# How to get a ListBox to select the same index as from main winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

while testing out my code. In my edit windows form a constructor exists below

```
public Edit(List<Item> i, int index)
{
    itemListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
    itemList = i;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

then the edit window is opened

```
var editor = new Edit(itemList, itemListBox.SelectedIndex);
editor.Show();
```

unfortunately i get

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What im trying to do is I have a main window with a listbox and when you double click an item a new form opens with a listbox and the same items. I want the item you double click on in the main window to be the item selected in the edit window that pops up.

Comment: how you bind itemListBox?

Comment: This error means that you did not instantiate the Object before you used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `InitializeComponent()` first then apply your code:

```
public Edit(List<Item> i, int index)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    itemListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
    itemList = i;
}
```

`itemListBox` is declared and initialized inside `InitializeComponent()` method.

Comment: Thankyou! now im getting "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

Comment: NVM fixed by updating the listbox before trying to select